# Clear a TextBox using MessageBox yes button

Tags: vb.net

I figured out how to clear the text box, but it clears out when I press <kbd>No</kbd> on the MessageBox. I want it to clear out if the user chooses <kbd>Yes</kbd>. If the user chooses <kbd>No</kbd> then I want to do nothing.

```
    Private Sub BtnFah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFah.Click
        Try
            Dim intFah As Integer
            intFah = CInt(TxtBoxTemp.Text)
            intFah = (intFah * 9) / 5 - 32
            If MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) Then
                TxtBoxTemp.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to compare the [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)

```
 Public Class Form1    
    Private Sub BtnFah_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnFah.Click
        Try
            Dim intFah As Integer
            intFah = CInt(TxtBoxTemp.Text)
            intFah = (intFah * 9) / 5 - 32
            If MessageBox.Show(intFah.ToString & ControlChars.CrLf & "Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "Result", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
                TxtBoxTemp.Text = String.Empty
            End If
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Would you like to start another temp conversion?", "System Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

[`MessageBox.Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3.aspx) returns a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx). You should check for `DialogResult.Yes`:

```
If MessageBox.Show(...) = DialogResult.Yes Then
   TxtBoxTemp.Text = String.Empty
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Q as variable and dim as msgboxresult to made the msgbox have result, if you press yes, textbox will be clear, if not, then it will return or does nothing

```
 Dim q As MsgBoxResult
            q = MsgBox("Your Question", vbYesNo)
            If q = vbYes Then
                TextBox1.Clear()
            Else
                Return
            End If
```

Comment: Have you check before downvote?

Comment: You could consider adding a comment about what the OP is doing wrong, what your code does, etc.

Comment: I just answer as what the user ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
If MessageBox.Show("Your Message", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
textbox.clear()
End If
```